# C++ reading and editing files

Tags: c++, file

I have a program in C++ that only asks the maths, physics, and P.E and saves in file and dat files is also the average of those values. So far so good but what I need now is that in can ask the user if they wants to check/visualize what is written on it and if he says no do they want do edit it.  I think that is a very hard task but it is also for me.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char url[]="notas.txt";
    float nota,
          media=0.0;
    FILE *arq;

    arq = fopen(url, "w");
    if(arq == NULL)
            printf("Error, it wasnt possible to open the file\n");
    else{
        printf("Maths eavluation: ");
        scanf("%f", &nota);
        fprintf(arq, "Matematica: %.2f\n", nota);
        media+=nota;

        printf("P.E evaluation: ");
        scanf("%f", &nota);
        fprintf(arq, " Educacao Fisica: %.2f\n", nota);
        media+=nota;

        printf("quemistry Eavluation: ");
        scanf("%f", &nota);
        fprintf(arq, " Fisico Quimica: %.2f\n", nota);
        media+=nota;

        media /= 3;
        fprintf(arq, "Media final: %.2f\n", media);
    }
    fclose(arq);

    printf("do u want to check the file??")
    //from here i dont know what to du ....XP

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to, I translate a bit more just ask ok?

Comment: @NathanOliver: because it can be compiled by the C++ compiler?

Comment: What are the requirements?  What do you need to the program to do after the input is read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the start of what you want. Because this is an assignment I have left you with some reading, and the remainder of the assignment. I have also translated much of the code to read in Portuguese.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

// seu códe
// Faça isso para ler o conteúdo do arquivo. Este não é testado
fclose(arq);
std::ifstream meu_arquivo;
meu_arquivo.open(url, std::ifstream::in);
std::cout << "Digite sim , se você quiser ver as notas: ";
std::string resposta;
std::cin >> resposta;
if (resposta == "sim" && meu_arquivo.good()) {
    // imprimir o conteúdo do arquivo.
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(infile, line)) {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }        
} else {
    meu_arquivo.close();
}

// Edição de um arquivo é deixado como um exercício . Por favor, leia 
// http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/ para mais detalhes.
```